# find the value for each row from another table

Tags: r

I have a data frame df that has a column indicating the grade level of each participant in that data frame. Grade levels range from "K" to "9". I have another table called "quantile" that contains the cut-off values of each quantile of the test score for each grade level. How can I create a new column in the df data which indicates the quantile of each students' test score based on the reference table "quantile"? The rule is that if a test score's value is less than the value of the cut-off, that test score belongs to the quantile of the cut-off value. And, if the test score is between 2 cut-off values, that test score is classified as the greater quantile. Thank you much!

Below is the dummy data and the result table I was looking for:

```
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("John", "Mary", "Emily"), "Grade" = c("8","9","10"), "Test Score" = c(5,61,60))
df

quantile <- data.frame("Grade" = c("8","9","10"), "Quantile 1" = c(10,15,20), "Quantile 2" = c(50,60,70),
                       "Quantile 3" = c(60,80,100))
quantile

result <- data.frame("Name" = c("John", "Mary", "Emily"), "Grade" = c("8","9","10"),"Test Score" = c(5,61,60), 
                     "Quantile" = c("Quantile 1","Quantile 3","Quantile 2") )

result
```

Comment: I voted for reopen since I'm no longer convinced this is "just a 'How to join'"-question.

Comment: @MartinGal: I think it was automatically closed yesterday! I did not close it, but I also got the workable solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We reshape the 'quantile' data from wide to 'long', then join with the 'df' dataset, and do a group by `summarise` to return the first 'Quantile' value where 'Test.Score' is less than 'value'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
quantile %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Grade, names_to = 'Quantile') %>% 
    left_join(df) %>% 
    group_by(Name, Grade) %>%
    summarise(Test.score = first(Test.Score), 
     Quantile = Quantile[which(Test.Score < value)[1]],
        .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    arrange(match(Name, df$Name))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Name  Grade Test.score Quantile  
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     
1 John  8              5 Quantile.1
2 Mary  9             61 Quantile.3
3 Emily 10            60 Quantile.2
```

Comment: sorry, I failed to mention this in the initial question. Supposing that I don't want to merge the 2 tables, but just want to create another column "quantile" in the df data set. This new column notes whether a student's test score belongs to which quantile based on their test score and the reference table. Can you advise in this case? I added another column in the df data set accordingly.

Comment: @AnnNg can you show the expeceted ouptut in the post.  Do you want both the quantile columns or not

Comment: @AnnNg i read your dscription as `How can I create a new column in the df data which indicates the value of quantile 1 for each student?` that implies only quantile 1

Comment: I adjusted my question as above. sorry for the confusion. hope it's clearer now! @akrun

Comment: can I ask another question as I develop my analysis? how would you adjust the above codes to group all test scores which are more than the cut-off values of Quantile 3 into another group, say "Quantile 4"?

Comment: @AnnNg Did you meant `summarise(Test.score = first(Test.Score), Quantile = if(value[Quantile == 'Quantile.3'] > first(Test.score)) 'Quantile.4' else Quantile[which(Test.Score < value)[1]])`

Comment: oh never mind, I played around with the codes and found a way to assign another category for values larger than Quantile 3's cut-off value.